# Problem about the existence of a de Bruijn cycle.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, graph-theory, induction

[image]

I have managed to prove parts (a) and (b). However, I am facing difficulty in proving part (c). I have tried using mathematical induction and so I first showed that the sequence for $n=1$ $b_1,b_2=(0,1)$ is a de Bruijn cycle. Then I assumed that for $k>1$ the sequence $b_1,b_2,...,b_{2^k}$ is a de Bruijn cycle. However when I am finding it difficult to show that the sequence $b_1,b_2,...,b_{2^{k+1}}$ will also be a de Bruijn cycle using the fact that $b_1,b_2,...,b_{2^k}$ is a de Bruijn cycle. Any help will be much appreciated.

**Edit:** This problem is from the Chapter $13$ of the book Introductory Combinatorics by Richard A Brualdi.

Comment: Why are you trying to use induction for part (c)? Why don't you just use the fact that you have a directed Eulerian circuit?

Comment: @bof I have made the edit. Is the information given by me sufficient?

Comment: @ bof I do not completely understand your first comment.

Comment: Various more details on that proof are given in the solution to Exercise 3 of [homework set 2 of my Math 5707 Spring 2017 class at UMN](http://www-users.math.umn.edu/~dgrinber/5707s17/hw2s.pdf). That said, some things are still left to the reader. (I use a multidigraph instead of a digraph, in order to make the $n=1$ case work out correctly; but for $n>1$ this makes no difference.)

Comment: @darijgrinberg thank you for sharing the pdf!

Comment: @ShreyAryan Could you please clarify why you're putting a bounty on part (c) on the problem ? Darij Grinberg's pdf tells it all (it's on pages 8-9 of the pdf). What more do you need ?

Answer (score 0):

**HINT:** Any binary sequence of length $n$ has an arc $b_k$ going out of it. Prove that the sequence equals $b_k$, $b_{k+1}$, ..., $b_{k+n-1}$.